# No Output is showing on Sublime text Python Program

Tags: python, build, sublimetext3, build-error, sublime-build

I want to run a simple simple print function in python with **sublime text**. My `Python.sublime-build` looks like this:

```
`"cmd": [C:\\Users\\Proteeti\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python36-32\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python"
```

Here is my simple output python program - [no output shows and says no build system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efhuY.png) .

What is occurring the problem here?

Comment: sublime text has a built-in  build system for python. Doesn't it work for you?

Comment: No, it didn't. 
Later I started using atom !